# Underscore in bar code code 39 disappear when scanning

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, code39

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZnpK.jpg)I use bar code code 39 extended to create bar code. In my software the code is good. Ex. 607A_QIT002-0004. When I scan the code I received 607A QIT002-0004. The _ have changed for a space. My scanner is in extended mode.

Do you have any idea why the _ is switchin for a space.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post an image of the barcode?  Hard to debug without seeing it.

Comment: It may be helpful to provide the vendor, model, and print command/configuration information for your barcode printer/barcode scanner, in order to obtain advice and answers.

Comment: @MarkWarren The image has been had to the post.

Comment: @kunif We tested the bar code with multiple scanner and cellphone with multiple apps and the results it's the same for all tested scanner. We used the free3of9x police to generate the bar code in a LIMS. The LIMS doesn't seem to be the problem because went we translate the bar code the underscore is there. After we exporte the code in a PDF report, no printer is used. Went we read the bar code with a scanner, than the _ change for a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there still a problem with the barcode image creation program, the specified command for it, or the printing tool?

The Honeywell Xenon 1900 GSR-1 barcode scanner. I have here reads as follows.
In both cases, the symbol notification format complies with AIM.

Code39 **Full ASCII Disabled**
Upper barcode

```
]A0607A UGS001-0004
```

Lower barcode

```
]A0XRF%OINTERFACE
```

Code39 **Full ASCII Enabled**
Upper barcode

```
]A4607A UGS001-0004
```

Lower barcode

```
]A4XRF_INTERFACE
```

---

**In Addition:**

"XRF_INTERFACE" of Lower barcode is created/encoded barcode corresponding to underscore.

In the upper bar code "607A UGS001-0004", the character string displayed separately is underscore, but the actual barcode creation/encoding seems to be whitespace.

For example, please try creating a barcode in a mode that prints HRI characters at the same time as the barcode.
Also, please compare the command to generate/print the barcode of "XRF_INTERFACE" with the command to generate/print the barcode of "607A_UGS001-0004".

---

**Note:**

By the way, since the response contents have been changed from the original ones, the comments attached are meaningless.

Comment: OP stated that he is using code39 extended and has his scanner configured for it as well.  code39ext can encode full ASCII.

Comment: Well, that's my misunderstanding. Delete it.

Comment: @kunif  thanks it's seem that you gave me a good idea. Went I write de code name manually and convert it, the _ is good. I will investigate my generator.

Answer (score 0):

Kunif this is my problem. With Code39 Full ASCII my bar code is generated with an _ but when I read it with any scanner I had on hand, configured for Full ASCII, the _ disappear.